# Django - Add css class to input field in admin

Tags: python, css, django, class

I have the following model:

```
class InfoBox(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(InfoBoxType)
    content = models.TextField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

I want to add a css class to my foreignkey. I've tried the following:

**forms.py**

```
class InfoBoxForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InfoBox
        widgets = {
            'type': ChoiceField(attrs={'class': 'hej'}),
        }
```

I've also tried this but with the same result...

```
class InfoBoxForm(forms.Form):

    type = forms.ChoiceField(
            widget=forms.ChoiceField(attrs={'class':'special'}))
```

**admin.py**

```
class InfoBoxInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = InfoBox
    extra = 0
    form = InfoBoxForm
```

But im only getting this:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

Im thinking that this would be pretty easy to do, so what am I doing wrong...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
widgets = {
    'type': Select(attrs={'class': 'hej'}),
}
```

This is the correct widget for your field.

If you don't want to overwrite the widget, you can use:

```
self.fields['type'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'hej'
```

in the form's init method